# Why kid is missing in Azure DevOps System.AccessToken?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

System.AccessToken is can be used as a means of authenticating requests to the Azure DevOps REST APIs from within a pipeline

- https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

In the header of this Access Token, the kid attribute is missing.

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "oOvcz5M_7p-HjIKlFXz93u_V0Zo"
}
```

Is there anyway to have in the Azure DevOps Access Token the kid field ?

Answer (score 0):

To get **`kid`** field in Azure DevOps access token, you can generate **OAuth token** using Azure AD to call DevOps REST API.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added **Azure DevOps permissions** like below:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to the permissions like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <appID>
grant_type:client_credentials
scope: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/.default
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), I got **`kid`** field successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @sridevi for your answer. We need to reuse the access token of the Azure Devops pipeline. Not the one of your App registred in Azure AD! Registring an app for each pipeline is not a scalable approach.